# DbGeogrphy Выделение области из области

Tags: c#, .net, yandex-geocoding-api, геометрия

не понимаю почему так работает метод Intersection.

Контекст проблемы.
Yandex Map. Есть заранее выделанная область(А) и в ней мы выделил область(Б)
и теперь я хочу получать значение области А, из который вытащили Б, и отдельно хранить область А и Б.

Для проверки результатов использовал
https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/

1. Данные с фронта, пришли корректные(фото 1. [image: Фото 1]
2. Перевод данных в DbGeorpahy, все окей.
3. Выделяю из старой области новую через Intersection, и получаю фигу(на фото)[image: Фото 2]
   Длинная линий к центру относится к объекту на Фото1.
   Мое понимание работы метода, или появляется два объекта. Внешний объект и внутренний должен получатся без всяких линий

Надеюсь ясно поведал об проблеме. Всем большое спасибо.

Comment: Знаете, выглядит корректно. Многоугольник с дырой иногда так и записывают.

Comment: Возможно, просто я когда отправляю на фронт такие данные, он так же рисует эту линию,что выглядит как баг. Я все же думаю что может я не полностью понимаю работу этого метода

Comment: Два встречных ребра соединяют дырку с внешней границей. Если требуется записать многоугольник с дыркой (два цикла ребер) в нотации простого многоугольника (один цикл ребер), это единственный способ. Вы видите лишние рёбра, зато площадь описана верно.